# Azure - Restrictions on reserving IP in another location?

Tags: azure, ip

Our Azure subscription was setup in Canada but a lot of our websites and services are hosted in North Europe as that is where our head office is.  I am trying to reserve an IP in North Europe with the following PowerShell command but I get the following error:

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -Location "North Europe"
New-AzureReservedIP : BadRequest: The location constraint is not valid
```

This command returns a new IP no problem:

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedIP –Location "Central US"
```

Are there restrictions getting reserved IPs from other locations?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully run your exact command.  Can you try running your command again?  Perhaps there was just a transient error.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error.  Maybe because we are still on the free trial?  We are still getting everything setup.